# How to reissue a delegated token after max lifetime passes for a spark streaming application on a Kerberized cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kerberos

We are using a headless keytab to run a long-running spark streaming application. The token is renewed automatically every 1 day until it hits the max life limit. The problem is token is expired after max life (7 days) and we need to restart the job. Is there any way we can re-issue the token and pass it to a job that is already running? It doesn't feel right at all to restart the job every 7 days only due to the token issue.

Comment: That's exactly why Spark has `--principal` and `--keytab` command-line options (mapping to Spark properties, but beware, properties name has changed in 2.3 or 2.4)

Comment: BTW what do you mean by _"using a headless keytab"_? Create a Kerberos ticket and let Spark find it in the local cache ; pass JAAS conf to Spark and let it create the ticket itself _(which will fail with Hadoop because of its custom tweaks on top of Java libraries)_ ; pass Spark conf to let it manage ticket renewal by-the-book?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter This is exactly the way we use it. Yarn will renew the token every 24 hours automatically until it reaches the max lifetime. After that, the token cannot be renewed anymore and it needs to be issued again. Hence, we are restarting the job which is not reasonable on the production environment.